# John Rebbler/Latour of New Orleans brickwall and adoption

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, adoption, louisiana

My great, great grandfather, John E. Latour was always listed as the son of James A. Latour and Emma C. *Lacqueret* in different family trees. I had no luck for years finding much about this couple, especially Emma, as her surname doesn't seem to exist at all. It occurred to me that Lacqueret might be a different spelling of Lacoure. I then found a birth record that lists that he was born to Emma C. *Lacoure* and John Rebler in New Orleans 17 Feb. 1880 and with this new information, was able to find an 1880 Census of New Orleans for John and Emma Rebbler, listing them as married with 2 sons, John (appropriately aged) and George.

I also found a marriage record of Emma *Lacquevet* and John Rebler, married in 1877. This couple also had a daughter who died when she was three, around 1884. That's the last date I can find anything else about the John Rebler/Emma Lacoure family.

Emma and James show up together for the first time in the 1900 Census as having been married 12 years, with sons George and John and other children. They are listed as James' sons, not step-sons.

John Rebler also shows up in the 1900 census, married to a woman named Mary  for the last 16 years and lists their children. This would put the year of their marriage the same as the year of the death of his daughter with Emma. He is listed as a barber from Baden, Germany in both this census and the one with Emma in 1880.

John Emile Latour is listed in a social security application with parents Emma C. *Lacqueret* and James A. Latour.

Emma is listed in the find-a-grave index with unknown birth information, buried in Greenwood Cemetery as Emma C. Latour in 1926 (wife of James). In some census records with James, her father is from Germany and her mother is from France and in others, both of her parents are listed as having been born in Louisiana.

John E. Latour married Gustavie Eugenie Latour in 1910 in New Orleans and they had my great grandmother, Alice.

Apparently John was adopted by his step father, James Adolph Latour. I feel like this is the same woman because the name Emma C. Lacqueret is so peculiar and specific and the sons birth dates, names and places line up.

Does the adoption of John E. Latour by a stepfather sound like a reasonable assumption despite that John Rebler went on to have his own family? With the strange variations in spelling of the names Rebler and Lacqueret, it's hard to tell. I can't find much at all on John's parent's ancestries.

Comment: I found them! I found a bunch of records that weren't available before. Should I delete this post?

Comment: If you prefer, you could self-answer the question, if you think there's useful information to share from the records that you've found. The surname changes look complex, so anything that clarifies them might be helpful to other researchers, for example. Particularly if online trees are in error.

Comment: This question as written is way too broad -- it has more than one question in it.  You could edit the question to make it more specific and then self-answer with the records you've already found. You don't have to pile all the questions about a single family into one question here -- we'd much rather see you ask one question per question.

Comment: My grandmother is Alice Frances LaTour. Her mother Gustavie Eugenie Latour was 16 when she married John E. LaTour and he was 32? Alice F. Had an older brother Paul?? What age was Gustavie?? Are we sure they were married and not related? Both surname of LaTour. Not sure he is even their "father".

Comment: Hi Aunt Janet. I'll share my research with you. Gustavie was pretty young and she wasn't with John for very long. John was adopted. His real last name was most likely Rebler.